# Limit number of buttons per row

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, underscore.js

I have 6 buttons that I'd like to render on my web page.

[image]

I'm mapping through an object of arrays in a JSON file through `map()`

```
template(x) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button bsStyle="primary"></Button>
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            {_(this.props.data).map((x) => this.template(x))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I limit each line to only have 3 buttons, instead of having however many it takes until it's forced to go down to the next line? I thought of just splitting up my the object arrays in the JSON file to two separate object arrays, so I can just make two `map()` calls? There seems to be a better and easier solution.

Comment: First step: think of how the resulted html layout should look like.

Comment: Would you consider a CSS solution?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean object of arrays? Can you show us some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the whole array into chunks (smaller arrays each of which contains only 3 elements) and push those arrays into `arrayOfChunks` (array of arrays) then, in the render function:

```
{arrayOfChunks.map(this.templateChunk)}
```

and the method:

```
templateChunk(chunk) {
    return (<div className="row">
            chunk.map(this.template)
    </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My React knowledge is limited so my syntax is probably off but what this does in the render function is return an array of row divs each containing 3 buttons. I think an easier solution is using `flex-box` with your css which would allow you to specify how many elements you want on row.

```
render() {
  return this.props.data.reduce((prev, curr, ind, arr) => {
    if (ind + 1 % 3 === 0) {
      prev.push(createRow(arr.splice(ind - 2, ind + 1)));
    }
    return prev;
  }, [])
}

createRow(arr) {
   return (
        <div className="row">
            {arr.map((x) => this.template(x))}
        </div>
    )
}

template(x) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button bsStyle="primary"></Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```